# Convert uint32_t in to 4 bytes (chunks) and output values in Hexadecimal notation considering Little- or Big-endian systems

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, hex, decimal

Just for exercise purpose, I'm trying to disassemble 'int' in to char and print out values in decimal as wel Hex format. i tried various solutions from other questions here in stack and several other places, like: https://dev-notes.eu/2019/07/Display-char-as-Hexadecimal-String-in-C++/
but nothing seams to work.

**updated code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // std::setfill

unsigned char* intToByte(const unsigned int& N);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::ios_base::fmtflags f( std::cout.flags() );

    // Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001328
    int num = 1;
    if(*(char *)&num == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "\nLittle-Endian\n" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Big-Endian\n" << std::endl;
    }

    int arr[4] = {1,5,-3, 2200};
    int i = 0, j = 0; // automatisch NULLL;
    for(; i < 4; i++){
        unsigned char *result = intToByte(arr[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            //std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << (unsigned char)result[j] << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::setfill('0')
                      << std::setw(2)
                      << std::uppercase
                      << std::hex
                      << (0xFF & static_cast<unsigned>(result[j]))
                      << " "
                      << std::endl;
            std::cout.flags(f);
        }
        delete result;
    }

    return a.exec();
}

unsigned char* intToByte(const unsigned int& N) {

    std::ios_base::fmtflags f( std::cout.flags() );
    unsigned char* byte = new unsigned char[4];
    //if constexpr (std::endian::native != to_endianness)
    std::cout << "intToByte ";
    byte[0] = (N >> 24) & 0xFF;
    //std::cout << "byte[0] " << byte[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setfill('0')
              << std::setw(2)
              << std::uppercase
              << std::hex
              << (0xFF & static_cast<unsigned>(byte[0]))
              << " ";
              //<< std::endl;
    std::cout.flags(f);
    byte[1] = (N >> 16) & 0xFF;
    //std::cout << "byte[1] " << byte[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setfill('0')
              << std::setw(2)
              << std::uppercase
              << std::hex
              << (0xFF & static_cast<unsigned>(byte[1]))
              << " ";
              //<< std::endl;
    std::cout.flags(f);
    byte[2] = (N >> 8) & 0xFF;
    //std::cout << "byte[2] " << byte[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setfill('0')
              << std::setw(2)
              << std::uppercase
              << std::hex
              << (0xFF & static_cast<unsigned>(byte[2]))
              << " ";
              //<< std::endl;
    std::cout.flags(f);
    byte[3] = N & 0xFF;
    //std::cout << "byte[3] " << byte[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setfill('0')
              << std::setw(2)
              << std::uppercase
              << std::hex
              << (0xFF & static_cast<unsigned>(byte[3]))
              << " "
              << std::endl;
    std::cout.flags(f);

    return byte;
}
```

It only seems to 'decode' the first value in the array correct and misses out on the remaining indexes, here is the output:

**updated output**

```
Little-Endian

intToByte 00 00 00 01 
00 
00 
00 
01 
intToByte 00 00 00 05 
00 
00 
00 
05 
intToByte FF FF FF FD 
FF 
FF 
FF 
FD 
intToByte 00 00 08 98 
00 
00 
08 
98
```

Comment: Characters will always be printed as *characters*. Use `unsigned int` instead. And use a `std::vector`, which will get rid of the memory leak you have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, where should i change? changing 'arr' array to unsigned causes other due to the '-1' value',  i saw a 'vector' solution, but wanted to stick to low level fur 'training' purpose, where is the mem leak?

Comment: The "correct decoding" isn't printed by `intToByte`, it's printed by the loop in `main`; `0xFF & result[j]` is an `int`, not a `char`. (And it only prints the first result because your `for(; j < 4; j++)` loop only executes once.)

Comment: @molbdnilo indeed it looks like it, i only get the first value of the arr printed in char but the outer loop does iterates to '3' but nothing is outputted on the reaming 3 iterations, what would be the cause of that?

Comment: Since you have a fixed-size array, then perhaps `std::array<std::uint8_t, 4>`. Use both in the `intToByte` function, and as return-type. Then when printing you need `static_cast<unsigned>(result[j])` otherwise the byte will be printed as a character.

Comment: @NaturalDemon The inner loop iterates to `j == 4` on the first iteration of the outer loop, so `j < 4` is false on the remaining outer iterations. (Get in the habit of declaring and initializing your loop variables in the loop. It will save you much headache.)

Comment: You don't reset j to zero in your inner loop. Sticking to the convention of initialising variables inside the for loop would avoid this issue

Comment: @AlanBirtles ah, yeah these are these frikking minor things you can pull your hairs while you fail to see them, lol
I advanced one error, Thank you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thnx, i have updated the code in the question as well the output. the code now seams to formatted as it should, all is displayed correctly accept for the negative value in the array. displaying '4294967293' in HEX although it's the correct decimal value.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about your need for negative numbers... Just convert to plain `int` instead of `unsigned`. And use `std::int8_t` as the array-element data-type instead.

Comment: Oh and don't update your question to "solve" the problem you ask about, because then your question won't actually *have* that problem, making the question moot and kind of useless. If no-one writes an answer, you could do it yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude for once i did answer my own question and updated the code a bit further, hope people will like it.

Comment: I think this answer I gave a few weeks ago may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77667545/problem-with-big-endian-and-little-endian/77667939#77667939

Comment: @selbie Your code is pretty cool, I'll safe it, but i 'answered' my own question and posted also some code below this.

Answer (score 0):

Witch some help from the people here I'm gonna answer my own question.
The code takes in to account Little- and Big-endian systems and puts out accordingly.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <iostream>
//#include <format>
#include <locale>

union foo
{
    uint32_t integer;
    unsigned char byte[4];
};

typedef foo value;

char* intToByte(const value& N);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
    std::ios_base::fmtflags f( std::cout.flags() );

    // Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001328
    int num = 1;
    if(*(char *)&num == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "\nLittle-Endian\n" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Big-Endian\n" << std::endl;
    }

    int arr[4] = {1,5,-3, 2200};
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(; i < 4; i++){
        char *result = intToByte(value{static_cast<uint32_t>(arr[i])});
        if(*(char *) & num == 1)
        {
            // Little-Endian System
            for(j = 4; j != 0; j--){
                std::cout << std::uppercase << std::hex << std::showbase << (0xFF & static_cast<char>(result[j - 1])) << " ";
                std::cout.flags(f);
                ;
                if((j-1) == 0) std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Big-Endian System
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                std::cout << std::uppercase << std::hex << std::showbase << (0xFF & static_cast<char>(result[j])) << " ";
                std::cout.flags(f);
                if(j == 3) std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
        delete result;
    }

    return a.exec();
}

char* intToByte(const value& N) {
    char* byte = new char[4];
    std::cout << "intToByte " << std::uppercase;
    byte[0] = (N.byte[0] & 0xFF);
    std::cout  << std::hex << std::showbase << (0xFF & static_cast<char>(byte[0])) << " ";
    byte[1] = (N.byte[1] & 0xFF);
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << (0xFF & static_cast<char>(byte[1])) << " ";
    byte[2] = (N.byte[2] & 0xFF);
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << (0xFF & static_cast<char>(byte[2])) << " ";
    byte[3] = (N.byte[3] & 0xFF);
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << (0xFF & static_cast<char>(byte[3])) << std::endl;
    std::cout.flags(f);
    return byte;
}
```

the output:

```
Little-Endian

intToByte 0X1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0X1 
intToByte 0X5 0 0 0
0 0 0 0X5 
intToByte 0XFD 0XFF 0XFF 0XFF
0XFF 0XFF 0XFF 0XFD 
intToByte 0X98 0X8 0 0
0 0 0X8 0X98
```